# Can I use an old Nikon SB-50DX with the D5500?

Tags: nikon, hotshoe-flash, compatibility

I just purchased a Nikon D5500 to replace my old D100 (yes, it has been that long).  I was wondering if and how I can use my SB-50DX flash with it.  I'm not clear on which mode it has to be in or what settings to use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The information you seek can be found on pges 327-328 of the [D5500 Reference Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/ETOYI00bfdW602XchPU57r5bLc70/D5500RM_(En)03.pdf):

> **Other Flash Units**
>
> The following flash units can be used in non-TTL auto and manual modes. Use with the camera in exposure mode **S** or **M** and a shutter speed of 1/200 s or slower selected.
>
> [image]
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Notes on Optional Flash Units**
>
> Refer to the Speedlight manual for detailed instructions. If the flash unit supports CLS, refer to the section on CLS-compatible digital SLR cameras. The D5500 is not included in the “digital SLR” category in the SB-80DX, SB-28DX, and SB-50DX manuals.
>
> If an optional flash unit is attached in shooting modes other than [no flash], [night vision], and [selective color], the flash will fire with every shot, even in modes in which the built-in flash can not be used.